In-App Messaging Conversation Status
I'm implementing the In-App Messaging SDK for both Android and iOS apps. I see that iOS provides conversation statuses(SMIConversationStatus) such as UNKNOWN, OPEN, and CLOSED. Does the Android SDK offer similar conversation statuses? If not, is there any way to determine if a conversation is open or closed on Android?
